# Como detectar o scroll no início e fim de uma div com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso detectar quando o `scroll` da página (independente se for a rolagem do mouse ou a barra lateral do navegador) passar por uma determinada `div`, e identificar o inicio e o fim dela, pois preciso aplicar uma animação quando a rolagem estiver passando por ela. Será que alguém tem uma ideia de por onde começar pelo menos?

Comment: Não seria melhor definir uma coisa ou outra? Por exemplo, quando a div aparecer toda na tela?

Comment: Bom, acho que funcionaria essa ideia de a div aparecer toda na tela, não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: Vou colocar uma resposta que detecta quando a div estiver toda na tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode detectar através da rolagem quando a div aparecer por completo na janela (veja explicações no próprio código). Usei como exemplo uma `div` com a classe `.mdiv`, aí você altera de acordo com a classe, id ou outro seletor que estiver usando.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){ // dispara o evento scroll da janela
   
   var div_heigh = $(".mdiv").height(); // pega a altura da div
   var win_heigh = window.innerHeight; // pega a altura da janela
   var win_scrol = $(this).scrollTop(); // pega o valor da rolagem da janela
   var div_topo  = $(".mdiv").offset().top; // distância da div até o início do documento
   var distancia = div_topo - win_scrol - win_heigh; // distância da div até a borda inferior da janela
   
   // se a distância da altura da div à borda inferior da janela for menor ou igual a 0
   if(distancia <= -div_heigh){
      $(this).off("scroll"); // cancelo o evento "scroll" para não entrar novamente no "if"
      console.log("a div apareceu toda!");
   }
   
});
```

```css
.esp{
   height: 500px;
   background: yellow;
}

.mdiv{
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="esp">Role para baixo</div>
<div class="mdiv">Minha div</div>
<div class="esp">Espaçador</div>
```

Comment: Legal, e será que tem como identificar quando ela deixa de aparecer toda na tela?

Comment: Cara, estava vendo aqui, depende muito do que vc quer fazer, se vai executar alguma coisa apenas uma vez ou sempre que a div aparecer toda, quando ela sair toda da tela. Eu fiz o código aqui, mas aí tem que definir esses critérios para que não fique executando o mesmo código toda vez que faz scroll. Veja no JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcw7uvks/2/

Comment: Na verdade é o seguinte, estou tentando fazer um parallax em uma imagem que fica posicionada em uma coluna a esquerda desta div, por isso queria identificar ela quando estivesse passando com o scroll. Vai ser assim tem uma imagem de fundo da linha toda que já tem um parallax e agora preciso criar esse outro parallax nesta outra imagem. Talvez minha lógica esteja errada.

Comment: Blz.. tô só um pouquinho ocupado aqui, mas vamos analisar sim a questão direitinho. Me parece ser simples, é que preciso analisar com mais profundidade. Eu te aviso.

Comment: Tranquilo, se puder me ajudar amanhã agradeço, e já deixo aqui meu obrigado até agora!

Answer (score 0):

Usa [essa](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) biblioteca, ela detecta automaticamente quando você está descendo o scroll, mas agora algo que você terá de usar é o `data-aos-offset="pixels"`. Há uma outra biblioteca que eu usava, só não estou lembrado, dps posto aqui. Ela detecta quando a div está dentro da janela.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }

.nothing {
background: black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.animated {
background: red;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  AOS.init()
 }
</script>


<div class="nothing"></div>
<div class="animated" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="10"></div>
```

Vá mexendo no `data-aos-offset` conforme a necessidade de cada div sua, e claro dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#-how-to-use-it) para poder colocar suas proprias animações